# New to R, Trying to generate a Grouped Bar chart

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

```
   A  B  C  D
Xy 10 20 30 40
Yz -4 6  10 15
```

I want to create a Grouped Bar chart showing `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` on x-axis and `Xy`,`Yz` as two stacked charts for `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`, respectively.

Thanks in Advance.

I tried using `barplot`, but couldn't plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a matrix `X`:

```
X <- rbind(1:4 * 10, c(-4, 6, 10, 15))
colnames(X) <- LETTERS[1:4]
rownames(X) <- c("Xy", "Yz")
#     A  B  C  D
# Xy 10 20 30 40
# Yz -4  6 10 15
```

As a start, you can do:

```
barplot(X, names.arg = colnames(X), legend.text = rownames(X),
        args.legend = list(x="topleft", bty="n"), col = c(3,4))
```

[image]

Personally I think stack barplot is difficult to understand. I would choose to display each row of `X` side by side:

```
barplot(X, names.arg = colnames(X), legend.text = rownames(X),
        args.legend = list(x="topleft", bty="n"), col = c(3,4),
        beside = TRUE)
```

[image]